# Style in laravel 4 not loading

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel 4
at the beginning when had this routing

```
Route::get('/{szukaj?}', function($szukaj = NULL)
{

//return "dobry" . $szukaj;

    //return View::make('/tomi/index');
    return View::make('/tomi/index', array('szukaj' => $szukaj));
});
```

were displayed gut, but i use system blade and my routing change at such

```
Route::get('blade-home/{szukaj?}', function($szukaj = NULL)
{
return View::make('blade.home', array('szukaj' => $szukaj) );
});
```

and in this point not loading file css, have following path to css

```
<link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In case when is 1 routing then style work, in 2 not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an absolute path for your CSS file. Laravel even provides you an asset [helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers):

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Make it and gets error PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Asset' not found in